# htaccess redirects twice over www. looks like total mess...

Tags: .htaccess, url-routing, repeat

there!

This is my first htaccess on an html website and it keeps redirecting my http://www... requests to https://www.www... I'm unable to verify the entire property on the Google console...
Now, I seem to be unable to detect the problem! Can somebody help?
Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteEngine on
IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(order\.php|example\.html|anotherpage\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://wwww.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.html|\.gif|\.*|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
# Manually re-route portfolio/ requests to portfolio
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} blog/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1
# Hide extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# Disable Automatic Directory detection
DirectorySlash Off
# 404 json
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule \.json$ 404.json [L,NC]
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Prevent hotlinkinks of images
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example-half\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule \.(css|js|mng|mp3|mp4|mpg|mpeg|pdf|ogg|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp|png|webp|ico|)$ https://www.example-half.com/dontlinktomyimage.webp [NC,R,L]
# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype font/opentype
</ifModule>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ink-pause\/$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\-half\.com\/article" [R=301,L]
```

> Some more writing for I shall "explain more" when I do not see what else to say...

Comment: Indeed that dynamic configuration file itself looks like a total mess. Where do all those entries come from? What are you trying to implement there?

Comment: But certainly there _are_ indeed external redirections prepending a `www.` to the URL _regardless_ of whether it already is present... So the answer to your question apparently is: don't do that, either don't redirect, or add a condition _not_ to redirect in case that prefix is already present...

Comment: Hi! I've had used the cpanel static page generator when mine was in development and added later my code for I thought this one shall stay... Also, used the "redirect" option of the cpanel so I suppose it's indeed a mess... Perhaps, I shall start over... I need all my website to run over https... and then, the pages are HTML so I did not want to show the extension and also to consider with/without a trail...

Comment: My personal experience over the last 30 years in business: such tools create a mess, it makes much more sense to simply code the few rules yourself. That way you learn and know what you have done.

Comment: I begin to understand it just now... Thank you for taking the time! I'll start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right there on line 6 of your config file:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The destination of the rule includes www. in it, so www.example.com will become www.www.example.com.

You also don't need to state RewriteEngine on more than once per htaccess file.

Suggestion: You say this is your first .htaccess file but it's already looking rather complex and you're jumping straight into rewrite rules, which is one of the most challenging things to do for beginners. I'd suggest starting with something simpler before jumping into rewrite rules. If you're copying from an example for the purposes of letsencrypt or something, then try to stick as close to their example as possible.

Comment: Rewriting rules are not complex, but that actually is not the point. If the OP needs to implement some rewriting, then there is little sense in telling him "that is too complex for you" in my eyes...

Comment: I'm not saying he can't use them, I'm just saying he's trying to run before walking and should try something simpler first. RewriteRules can get complex and hard to understand very quickly. Even one of the original Apache devs said "mod_rewrite is voodoo"

Comment: THANK YOU so much! It was as simple as that and everything is running smooth! I've also performed the suggested changes and organized it better. Yes, I usually "ornament" things... suppose most writers do... :)